# album ID in Picasa from Android?

Tags: android, gdata-api, picasa

This is batty! The Google [GData Java client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) page says that GData doesn't support Android, and I should instead use the [Google API Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). The [Picasa sample for Android](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) has some Picasa-specific stuff, but to get it you have to use Mercurial and build it yourself. But this new library bears little resemblance to the [Picasa Web Albums Data API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html).

So after much pain I finally was able to parse back an Atom feed of a list of my public albums. But the AlbumEntry (the one from the Mercurial source repository---not the one online, which supposedly doesn't work with Android) has no AlbumEntry.id to tell me how to then list the contents of the album!

Has anyone succeeded in working with Picasa from Android? Not in 2007---like, recently?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to not having an ID to reference the album by-  That's because that was the way of doing it in GData.  To use the atom-based feed that the new sample you linked is using, you need to pull the edit link from the atom feed and reference it that way.  [This page](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.6.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html) has some details that'll help you out.

Comment: (Huh---I see these code samples were written by the same guy---and totally incompatible with the "official" Google samples, which are in turn incompatible with the "official" documentation.) In regard to your reply, which I appreciate, I should note that I already tried that---and got an invalid request error back from the server. Instead I'm now parsing out the ID from that link and using it in the /user/xxxx/albumid/yyyy format.